# In Maze Runner:Death Cure, do those who receive the cure made of Thomas' blood, become immune?

Tags: the-maze-runner

Does it grant the victims immunity to the Flare or is it just a temporary cure?

Comment: Note: Your post has come up in the Low Quality Post queue. While it isn't a bad post, it could use some more content in the question. Whimsical thoughts don't usually do too well, although they can sometimes. Providing some more context in your question, as well as any research you have done to find the answer is _highly_ recommended.

Comment: (-1) Please elaborate. Perhaps discuss your thoughts on what you believe the answer is, and with that, maybe share a theory or two. I will upvote it back once done so :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm guessing that would be correct as why would A. D. Janson threaten to shoot Thomas so he hands over the cure? If it was temporary then Rat man would try his best to keep Thomas alive so that he could make use of his blood. The whole point of the maze is to give off adrenalin, Thomas would have to be alive to have adrenalin running in his veins.